# Too many arguments found but 0 expected

Tags: flutter, dart

I keep getting these messages saying too many arguments 0 expected but 4 found and also positional arguments must occur before named arguments. Here's my code

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: double.infinity,
      width: 280.0,
      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Column(
              children: const [
                // logo
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      _SideMenuIconTab(
        iconData: Icons.home_outlined,
        title: "Home",
        onTap: () {},
      ),
      _SideMenuIconTab(
        iconData: Icons.search,
        title: "Search",
        onTap: () {},
      ),
      _SideMenuIconTab(
        iconData: Icons.download_for_offline,
        title: "Offline",
        onTap: () {},
      ),
```

Comment: can you provide whole code ?

Answer (score 0):

See how you have your `_SideMenuIconTab` inside `Container` but not in `Row`
Add this inside of `Row`

[image]

Comment: Can you include code-snippet instead of code-image

Answer (score 0):

Please update your code with below

```
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          height: double.infinity,
          width: 280.0,
          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: const [
                    // logo
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          );
}
```

If you want to add **_SideMenuIconTab** please share complete code along with the what you want to achieve. so we can check your code and find the exact solution. For now by updating your code with this, you will not face any error.

Comment: Well, they obviously *do* want the _SideMenuIconTab. So what is your code accomplishing other than deleting something they want?

Comment: If you have check that he has shared incomplete code without sharing what he want to achieve. So i have mentioned the same thing that please share those details for now he has misplaced the code so i have resolved that error.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your structure is just wrong. That is the fact and that is what your compiler is telling you. What you wanted it to look like is not something we could find out from the code you posted, so it's guesswork.

Maybe you meant the three `_SideMenuIconTab`s to go into one of the arrays that you created as the `children:` property of your `Row` and `Column`? Maybe you meant to create another `Row` or `Column` to put them in? Whatever it was you wanted to do, you need to find a widget that can hold multiple other widgets to put them in. They cannot just "be there".